# Start a Task without waiting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing, task

I am using asp.net mvc and I want to cache some data about user from database when he reaches the home page of the site.
So when user requests the Home page, I want to call an async method, which makes database calls and caches data.

Any examples of doing this would be great.

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((Action<object>)state =>
{
    //do your async work
}, null);
```

or `Task.StartNew(...)`

(sorry for the brief answer, this may take you on the right track or someone can edit this to show a full example, please?)

Comment: Can you help me the cache side as well, Lets say it takes me 2 seconds to cache the data using my Task.StartNew(...). If user happens to access this data before 2 seconds, how would I make the thread wait till the full data is read from database and cached.

Comment: in that case, you would save a the task in a static list/dictionary and would check if a task is already available. In that case, call task.Wait on it and then retrieve the Task.Result or access you cache object. (btw. don't miss HttpUtility.Cache)

Answer (score 38):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

    Task.Run(()=> DoSomeAsyncStuff());

    return View();
  }

  private async void DoSomeAsyncStuff()
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when `DoSomeAsyncStuff()` by itself just hung. I was trying to get something working as described [here](http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/).

Comment: You should always avoid using "async void" as a good practice. Instead use "async Task"

Comment: @Rukshod Yes, of course. I was just answering the question.

Answer (score 18):

For .NET Core I use this

```
_ = Task.Run(() => SomeAsyncFunction());
```

Comment: This helped me in my .net core project, thanks much!

Comment: this prevents static analysis warning ([CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014)) for not await the task ( which is exactly what we want )

Answer (score 14):

The top upvoted answers both suggest using `Task.Run`, which is a really bad practice for ASP.NET Core, since it might cause thread starvation (because `Task.Run` schedules a task to run on a thread pool, and thread pool threads are needed for http request handling).

If you really want to "fire and forget" a method that is (a) *truly asynchronous* and (b) the method takes care of all exceptions inside it, then just do:

```
_ = DoSomething();
```

Assuming the method is

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
}
```

Comment: not getting the results you've mentioned with this. code: https://pastebin.com/h1u7H0gu 



result: Started TestFeature0
Started WaitOneSecond0
Finished WaitOneSecond1001
Started WaitTenSeconds1001
Finished WaitTenSeconds11001
Finished TestFeature11001

Comment: you're using `Thread.Sleep` which is forbidden in `async`. Calling Thread.Sleep freezes the whole thing. Use `await Task.Delay()` instead.

Comment: interesting, why does Thread.Sleep work with _ = Task.Run(() => WaitTenSeconds()) but _ = WaitTenSeconds() doesn't. using Task.Delay does work with your suggestion

Comment: @kewur because `Task.Run` by definition, runs your code in a new thread. And that's what makes it dangerous (see my answer ^^^)

Comment: @Alex *"`Task.Run` runs your code in a new thread."* -- actually [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) runs the code on the `ThreadPool`.

Answer (score 3):

I would say you call the caching method via this:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(x=> CacheData());
```

In that way, you don't really keep the home page request waiting so the users get to see the home page immediately, while the caching happens in the background at the server.

PS: But yes you run a slight risk of app domain recycling screwing up your caching thread.